# How to backup all notes from the stock notes app in Froyo?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, backup, notes

Is there an easy way to backup/export notes from the stock notes app in Froyo? Alternatively, I'd like to know where said data gets stored, so I can manually copy them over to my PC.

Edit: I'm pretty sure the app came pre-installed on my device. The name of the app, as it looks from the app drawer is "Note pad."

Comment: I’ve always thought that Android doesn’t have a stock notes app. Are you sure it isn’t a notes app from the market? If it is then the answer will depend on which app it is.

Comment: It came pre installed. Im 100% sure. My device is a huawei u8150 and are you sure its not included in android? Because it's name is just "Notes" and looks really much like http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found out that this was pre-installed either by Huawei, or my telecom, as it resided in /cust/tata/in/app.

The notepad app is too bad as it doesn't allow anything else other than adding and deleting notes.

I solved my problem by manually opening each and every one of the notes, selecting all of them, tapping "copy" and then going to a file manager to open a text file. I then pasted it there, and saved them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

My notepad (aka `com.example.android.notepad`), resident of Motorola xt317 (android 2.3), has a sqlite database living in the phone. Download it with

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.android.notepad/databases/note_pad.db ./Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://android.stackexchange.com/a/73052/241313

Convert `.ab` into `.tar`:

```
adb backup -f com.example.android.notepad.2018-11-05.ab -noapk com.example.android.notepad
dd if=com.example.android.notepad.2018-11-05.ab bs=1 skip=24 > data.gzX
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - data.gzX | gunzip -c > data.tar
```

Extract `.tar` file:

```
tar xf data.tar
```

Optionally, create a `.tar.gz` file:

```
gzip -c data.tar > com.example.android.notepad.2018-11-05.tar.gz
```