# How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through "adb backup"?

Tags: backup, adb, restore

I have been backing up my Nexus 7 with `adb backup` to back up all files into an encrypted backup.  I see that you can restore from a backup with `adb restore`, but that would wipe all my existing data on the device.

How exactly would I extract one App's data from this encrypted backup file?

Comment: See also: [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23357/16575)

Comment: I believe none of the answers without using Java will work on encrypted phones. See my answer below summing up the use of nelenkov's app (github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor). Unfortunately Izzy's Adebar perl scripts ab2tar will not work on encrypted backup files. Similar: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23357/is-there-a-way-to-look-inside-and-modify-an-adb-backup-created-file

Comment: related-  `dd if=data.ab bs=1 skip=24 | openssl zlib -d | tar -xvf -`  mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533567/how-to-extract-or-unpack-an-ab-file-android-backup-file

Answer (score 142, accepted):

#### How to extract ab files

There is an [open source project](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) under the Apache 2.0 license,  written by [Nikolay Elenkov](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/) that will allow you to extract the .ab in to a tar file.

Usage:

```
java -jar abe.jar unpack <backup.ab> <backup.tar> <password>
```

#### Background

Just for reference of others, here is some background on the .ab file format.

The Android Backup (*.ab) file is a compressed [TAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) file. It is compressed using the [DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm. On top of that, there can be [AES encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) used. This is determined when you create the backup, if you enter a password then the backup is encrypted, otherwise; there is no encryption, it is only compressed.

The HEADER of the file is a little different than a normal DEFLATE archive. It contains information about the backup and looks like the following:

```
ANDROID BACKUP
1
1
none
```

The first line is the ["Magic" line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29). The next line is the version of the Android Backup file format. The next line is a boolean (true or false, 1 or 0) indicating if the file is compressed. The last line is the type of encryption. This example is not using any encryption. If there was a password, the line would read "AES-256". After that is the encryption cipher. If no password, then the DEFLATE "archive" starts.

It is compressed using the [Java Deflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html). Which, from a developers perspective,  causes issues if you want to use anything besides Java to extract it. I haven't been able to find anything that can deflate it using the same algorithm, even though all that I have found (for like C#) are supposed to follow the "SPEC".

If you are not sure how to really use that (which is beyond the scope of this answer) [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer) since v0.8.8.7 ([available here](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/releases)) allows you to do exactly this, and more, right from Explorer. You can read more about the features on [my blog](http://blog.twimager.com/2012/08/droid-explorer-0887-backup-feature.html) (yes, i know, shameless plug. I do that when it fits the question)

[image: unpack]

Comment: I would vote you up if I had the reputation, my god man thanks!

Comment: your welcome. I only know all that information because this is a feature that I just recently added to the Droid Explorer code base, so I had to do some research on it.

Comment: Hi Ryan, tried to use Droid Explorer but it fails to start complaining about Android SDK location, even though it is installed and I'm supplying the right path.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja Take a look at the [FAQ](https://de.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Home) for droid explorer. The last Q/A addresses your issue.

Comment: OK, have extracted the relevant 'com.app.name' folder from the tar but how do I use that to restore the app data? Simply copying the folder to sdcard/Android/data/ doesn't seem to work...

Comment: The resulting `tar` archive may have an incorrect header, I've found. The latest advice I've gotten is to run the following command on it, which didn't help. YMMV: `dd if=backup01.tar bs=24 skip=1 | zlib-flate -uncompress | tar xf -`

Comment: may be worth telling people where to click to install it without loading the whole thing into visual studio   https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GQUB.png

Answer (score 120):

Or with a one-liner:

```
( printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" ; tail -c +25 backup.ab ) |  tar xfvz -
```

Comment: Nice!  Do you also have the equivalent of "pack" (to take the uncompressed directory tree and create a .db file)?

Comment: Could you add an explanation to the answer.?

Comment: THIS is the best answer :D Works perfectly fine! Extracting now.

Comment: Explanation: author creates a standard Zlib file header for a `.tar.gz` file with `printf` command (`0x1F 0x8B` is a signature, `0x08` is the compression method, `0x00` are flags and 4 x `0x00` is timestamp), then appends to this header the contents of `backup.ab` file, starting from offset 25d. Such stream is a valid `.tar.gz` file, and the `tar xfvz` command recognizes it as such, so it can successfully uncompress the stream.

Comment: I made a backup with adb 1.0.36 (Revision 1.7.0.0+r33-2) and this method produced an error from zgip: ``invalid compressed data--format violated``

Comment: Very nice. Can it be modified to accept a decryption password?

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! As one of the commenters on a similar answer, I received an "unexpected end of file" error, but everything seems ok. And like @dailyglen, I'd quite like to know if this is reversible?

Comment: got same issue, *gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated tar: Child died with signal 13 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now*

Comment: @Matifou @Rache  As I have the same problem with `invalid compressed data` and I have set a password at backup, I suspect that as the problem. Since neither tar nor gzip support password protection, I guess, there is now way, this command can easily adjusted to ask for a password. :(

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with an encrypted backup? I recently upgraded my phone and chose to encrypt its file system. That gave me an encrypted backup and I had to resort to the far more complicated `abe.jar` method.

Comment: I tried every method given in all answers here, but I only get empty tar files. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JosefScript, its all for unencrypted ab files. Im in the same boat. Trying Izzy's answer below (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42224/95893) that uses perl, actually trying his GitHub app because its a pain to install the reqs for his script. I just posted a issue on his GitHub about how to use his ab2tar tool on encrypted. Let me know if you come up with anything, and Ill do the same, thx

Comment: 2x faster using dd than tail on my laptop:  

`(printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" && dd if=backup.ab bs=1M iflag=skip_bytes skip=24) | tar ztv`

Answer (score 37):

One more option is to use `bash`, `cat` and `gunzip` (`gzip`).

The full process could be this (**with an unencrypted backup**):

1. backup one app's data (for example "[Override DNS for KitKat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mx17.overridedns)"):

   ```
   $ adb backup -f net.mx17.overridedns.ab -noapk net.mx17.overridedns
   Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.
   ```
2. extract the compressed data

   ```
   $ dd if=net.mx17.overridedns.ab bs=1 skip=24 > compressed-data
   1285+0 records in
   1285+0 records out
   1285 bytes (1,3 kB) copied, 0,00745877 s, 172 kB/s
   ```
3. decompress the compressed data

   ```
   $ printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" \
       | cat - compressed-data | gunzip -c > decompressed-data.tar
   gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
   ```
4. "untar" the tar file

   ```
   $ tar xf decompressed-data.tar
   ```

Comment: Is the "unexpected end of file" to be expected?

Comment: The extraction in 2 surprisingly worked on an encrypted file. How is this possible? The decompression then failed with `gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated`. I assume the extraction succeeded, as `dd` reports `22763821+0 records in 22763821+0 records out`.

Comment: @TomRussell The extraction merely trims bytes off the start.

Comment: Isn't dd a bit of an overkill to just skip 24 bytes? This is also not failsafe unless `conv=noerror,sync iflag=fullblock` is added: https://superuser.com/a/1523120/910769 You might consider this answer: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/78183/340401

Answer (score 10):

Based on the information by others, now I know that the backup file is just a prefixed Deflated (GZip) stream, based on this information this simple program can unpack it for you:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

/** Run: javac unab.java && java unab backupfile.ab */
public class unab {
    private static final int BACKUP_HEADER_LENGTH = 24;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(args[0] + ".tar");
            try {
                if (in.skip(BACKUP_HEADER_LENGTH) != BACKUP_HEADER_LENGTH) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file while skipping backup header.");
                }
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024];
                int count;
                InputStream zip = new InflaterInputStream(in);
                while ((count = zip.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this because I don't have any of the Unix tools mentioned above, and it was easier than installing Cygwin or other tools.

**Advantages**:

- cross-platform
- simple (no esoteric parameters)
- no need for piping tools

**Disadvantages**:

- need a JDK (which you likely already have because you're messing with Android SDK)
- no support for encrypted backups
- need something to extract the resulting tar file (I use Total Commander)

To make it a command line tool create `unab.bat` with contents: `java -cp "%~dp0." unab %*` and the directory to `PATH`.

Comment: This is actually quite elegant solution - you can see right away what you are doing in small java code. Just use java (it is there on your machine most of the time already): put the code above into "unab.java", call "javac unab.java" from the command line and then call "java unab YUORFILE.ab" and that is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As the implicit question is also, "how to restore a single apps data", I would like to mention [this nifty script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adb-split/), that splits a given full-backup.ab in single-app.ab files.

It requires these jar files: [abe.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/files/) and [tar-bin-split.jar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tar-binary-splitter/files/).

At least for my testcase, it worked using the referenced resources.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using the Perl AdbBackupRoutines from [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27840175#post27840175). They have a few requirements, though: Perl obviously, plus `libterm-readkey-perl`, `libcrypt-cbc-perl`, and `libcrypt-pbkdf2-perl` (if your backups are unencrypted, you can skip the last dependency by simply commenting out line 103 of `backupdecrypt.pl` where it's included -- worked fine for me).

Usage is quite easy:

```
./backupdecrypt.pl [options] <backupfile.ab> <outfile.tar>
```

The resulting `.tar` file then can be investigated like any other tarball. Its structure is quite interesting in at least one aspect: it does not reflect the real paths where the files have been taken from (e.g. not `/data/data/com.app.name/databases/whatever.db`, but instead `apps/com.app.name/db/whatever.db`) -- which indicates an app backed-up on one device/ROM *might* be restored to any other device/ROM without trouble, as `adb restore` must figure out the real paths itself.

Comment: There's another tool (a little better maintained) that does this: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor

Comment: Thanks, @lid! I've also included a little shell-script (almost a one-liner only) with my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) (Android DEvice Backup And Report), which converts ADB backups (`.ab`) to `.tar.gz` Archives :)

Answer (score 4):

To add another option here's a Windows PowerShell version of the header manipulation:

```
$file_in = (Get-Location).Path + "\backup.ab"
$file_temp = (Get-Location).Path + "\temp.tgz"
[int32[]]$header = 0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file_in)
$bytesout = $header + $bytes[24..($bytes.Length - 1)]
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($file_temp, $bytesout)
```

You can try to use the tar executable in current Windows 10 versions 17063 or later to extract the file, however it seems that it currently doesn't handle the misformed file produced in this process as well as the linux version. YMMV:

```
tar -xvzf $file_temp
```

To get the full contents you can manually extract with 7zip or similar.
Or could combine with one of the answers from [Native .tar extraction in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776137/native-tar-extraction-in-powershell).

Comment: 7zip and also other archive tools feature command-line-tools

Comment: I like this technique, but I get an OOM (Out Of Memory) error when I try using it.  It's the next-to-last line in the PS script that seems to eat up all available RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to other answers, I *finally* got it using [nelenkov's app](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) and [the instructions from here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011811). I was trying to avoid the extra 800mb disk space for Java. Most phones are moving toward encrypted by default, and I think nelenkov's app is the only solution that works well with encrypted.

[Here is a direct link to nelenkov's compiled jar release](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/releases/tag/20181012025725-d750899). Please check if its the latest, then follow the instructions from the link above. It has more info about Helium and Splitting an ab file up in to individual app files. And also a way to change apps not set to use adb backup without root. Substitute `abe-all.jar` if using this release file.

> 1. Convert the original adb backup to tar format:
>
> `java -jar abe.jar unpack nexus7.ab nexus7.tar <password>`
>
> 2. Extract the contents of the tar archive. This should be done on a
>    filesystem where the permissions of the files inside the tar are
>    preserved, for example using linux, mac or bsd. Up to two folders may
>    appear, apps and shared:
>
> `tar -xvf nexus7.tar`

Now you should have new folders to look in. Now you can see which apps are backed up and which arent.

BTW, [Izzy's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42224/95893) is good, but his script requires several perl modules to be installed, the 3rd of which I couldnt find easily. His app is full featured, but find `adb2tar` in `Adebar-master/tools/`. Again, it doesnt work with encrypted ab files though.

Comment: I wasn't aware `ab2tar` requires any Perl modules. What it basically does is what rmil's answer describes ;) But maybe it did in an older version…

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Linux environment:

```
dd if=backup.adb skip=1 bs=24 | zlib-flate -uncompress | cat > somewhere.tar
tar xvf somewhere.tar
```

Comment: Duplicate to above as eg https://android.stackexchange.com/a/73052/340401 ?

Comment: @Cadoiz nope, check the commands closely. This here is rather what `ab2tar` from Adebar does (see the answer of alchemy).

Comment: What's the point of piping stdin through `cat`? Delete the entire `| cat` step in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest binary of the [Android Backup Processor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/android-backup-processor/files/android-backup-processor-20210728-bin.zip/download). Once downloaded, extract the zip file and run:

`java -jar abp.jar unpack <backup.ab> <backup.tar> <password>`

###### Commands

```
Usage:
    info:       java -jar abp.jar [-debug] [-useenv=yourenv] info <backup.ab> [password]
    unpack:     java -jar abp.jar [-debug] [-useenv=yourenv] unpack <backup.ab> <backup.tar> [password]
    pack:       java -jar abp.jar [-debug] [-useenv=yourenv] pack <backup.tar> <backup.ab> [password]
    pack-kk:    java -jar abp.jar [-debug] [-useenv=yourenv] pack-kk <backup.tar> <backup.ab> [password]
```