# permanently decrypt my android

Tags: encryption

I have encrypted my android.

I now have these problems:

- I want to switch on and login:
  The system boots, I the primary user, type my password, the system boots, I type my password (This is a pain).
- Another user wants to switch on and login: System boots, they track me down, I type my password, system boots, they login.
- We don't shutdown: A bad person finds the device and steals my data, because it is not encrypted.

So now I with to undo the encryption. How do I do this?

---

Device: `Hudl2`.
Android Version: `4.4.2`.

Comment: For the third point, that "bad person" still needs a password to unlock the screen. For the remaining part, we'll need at least to know what Android version that (a bit uncomon) device is running.

Comment: Added version. @izzy if it where true that the “bad person” would need the password to unlock the screen, to be able to get to the data, then we would not need to encrypt the device. We are assuming that the “bad person” is not playing by the rules. Maybe they open the device and look at the ram direct. Maybe something else.

Comment: To "open the device and look at the [storage] direct" (usually with a JTAG device), they need to shut down the device first. Doing so, they'd need to decrypt again. To access it via ADB, they need to unlock the device and "authorize" their computer.

Comment: @Izzy If I just pulled the battery, connected a JTAG, and poked around in RAM. I could probably find something. Maybe even the encryption key (Password). You would be surprised how long DRAM can remember stuff with no power, and I would only have to drop the power for less than a second.

Comment: I don't doubt that, given enough effort, everything can be "cracked". Question is whether it's worth that effort – for the average user it is not. But let's stop that discussion (this is not a forum, and you don't want the encryption anyway). For Kitkat (which you stated your device is running), turning encryption off entirely should be possible. I have not done that (didn't encrypt in the first place), but AFAIK the process involves a factory-reset. Have to leave the answer for someone else.

Comment: See: [Ways to remove android device encryption](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/52046/16575), and also check [other answered `encryption` questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[encryption]+answers%3A1).