# Moving/copying an Appliction from one Tab 4 to another Tab 4

Tags: applications

How do I copy/move an application installed on one Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 to another Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.  The application is no longer available on Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways, depending on whether you only want to copy the app – or the data along:

- you can use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) from your PC to backup the app from the original device and restore it to the other. For details, see:

  - [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) (you will need that on your PC)
  - [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) (for ADB Backup itself)
  - [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575)
  - [our backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)
- without a PC being involved, the very same can be achieved using [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) on both devices
- there are several apps to extract the `.apk` files of installed apps. These can be used then for [side-loading](/questions/tagged/side-loading) the app to the other device. Several suitable candidates can be found [in this list](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_132).
- You also can check on [alternative markets](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/alternative-markets/info) whether the app is available there.