# retrieving and classifying Notes with time and date of creation

Tags: applications, system-apps, notes

I wrote hundreds of messages in 'Notes' of my smartphone (the system app), and I would like to retrieve them and put them in a CSV file, (or Excel) with one column for the content of the message, and another with time and date of creation of the note. Is it possible?

My device is Huawei Y330-U01

Android 4.2.2

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. To give a good answer on that, we need a few more details: which device and Android version are you using? There are hundreds of "Notes" apps, and each manufacturer makes its own choice for each of its devices (well, almost). Also: is your device rooted? Can you use [ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)? What OS are you using on your computer? These details help for "unconventional solutions". Good luck!

Comment: My device is Huawei Y330-U01

Android 4.2.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get notes created using "Notes" default app and export them to PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128678/get-notes-created-using-notes-default-app-and-export-them-to-pc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible (at least in my device)  and I've provided a generalized idea using my Mediatek device running Android 4.2.1.

The idea is very simple. Most of the notes apps I tried so far stores the notes inside a `.db` file located in their personal space under `/data`. We have to get the relevant `.db` file(s) and then export it into a `.csv` file.

### For a non-rooted device

1. Find the package name of your "Notes" app. You can use [ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb) command by launching the app in the foreground and entering the following ADB command from PC:

   ```
   adb shell dumpsys activity | grep mFocused | awk -F 'u[0-9]+ ' '{print($2)}' | cut -d '/' -f 1
   ```

   The output shown for my device was:

   ```
   com.mediatek.notebook
   ```

   It is possible that the aforesaid command may not work for your device, so either you troubleshoot it by yourself, or install an app like [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en) → launch your "Notes" app → launch **OS Monitor** → locate your "Notes" app amongst the processes and tap on it to see the value corresponding to `Process`.

   <sub>Suggested by [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) -- If all else fails, then try [App Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser) or [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) to find package name. I tried the former and it does the job nicely.</sub>
2. Take backup of your "Notes" app by issuing the following ADB command:

   ```
   adb backup <PACKAGE>
   ```

   where `<PACKAGE>` is the package name of the app whose backup you want to take. The file will be saved as `backup.ab` in the directory from where ADB is executed.

   In my case, I ended up with the backup file `backup.ab` (~1.7KiB) in my Home directory of GNU/Linux using the command:

   ```
   adb backup com.mediatek.notebook
   ```

   <sub>This step is needed because I'm unaware (as a non-root user) of any other way to get my hands on an app's internal files residing in `/data`.</sub>
3. The `.ab` file cannot be opened in my PC so I used [Android Backup Extractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/) (see usage in its `README.txt`) to convert into `.tar` archive which then can be opened by any archive viewer (like Ark, WinRAR, and so on).

   <sub>Some other methods to unpack the `.ab` file are mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/96277).</sub>
4. Open the converted file (`.tar` for me) and locate `.db` file under **apps**→`<PACKAGE>`→**db**→`<.db>`.
5. Open that `.db` in an SQL viewer like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). You can then export the file into `.csv` using **File → Export → Table(s) as CSV file**.

### For a rooted device:

1. You can either follow all the aforementioned instructions, or copy the `.db` file(s) from `/data/data/<PACKAGE>/databases/<.db>` into your PC and proceed with aforesaid step 5.
2. You may try [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor&hl=en) to view the database(s) directly on Android if you only intend to see the content of your "Notes" app, since data and creation time probably would be visible in `.db` file.

We're good to go now!

Comment: My method works on user installed apps like [Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.jacobras.notes) or [Simplenote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.automattic.simplenote) as well.