# Get notes created using "Notes" default app and export them to PC

Tags: notes, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I'm searching a way for get all my notes<sup>1</sup> created in my Samsung Galaxy Ace II<sup>2</sup> and export them to PC "in separately or unified text file (.txt)".

After hours of searching, I found [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/113220); however, I can't follow the provided steps and the final target is *quite* different from the linked question.

As an alternative, I found a software called [Remo Recover for Android](http://www.remorecover.com/android/) but this app *looks like* it cannot access the saved notes.

In another search, [this answer](http://www.simplydroid.com/forum/transfer-memos-samsung-galaxy-y-samsung-galaxy-ace-57111.html#post81980) suggests:

- Select memo/note.
- Select "Share" or "Send" selected note.

The problem with this solution is that I have more than 100 notes and some of them has 1500 characters, and making this manually takes much time.

I'm looking for a solution<sup>4</sup> that download/export the saved notes from my smartphone and save them in my PC; those notes should<sup>2</sup> be stored as `.txt` files (separately, or in a unified `.txt` file).

---

<sup>1</sup> The app used for taking notes/memos is the default one integrated in the smartphone.

[Here's a image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryplt.png); I didn't find the name or another useful information about the default note/memo app.

<sup>2</sup> My smartphone has not been rooted or modified; no additional notes app is in the smartphone.

<sup>3</sup> Other acceptable file extensions could be XSL or DOCX.

<sup>4</sup> I'm not sure if this question should be created on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) too, because the possible solution could be a free or commercial app / software.

---

Edit: Package name of Notes app: `com.sec.android.app.memo`. [Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128678/get-notes-created-using-notes-default-app-and-export-them-to-pc#comment159991_128678)

Screenshot:

<sub>Click image to enlarge</sub>

[image: Screenshot of my smartphone using _Android System Info_]

Comment: 1) What is the package name of your Notes app? If needed, read [View app's full package name?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767) 2) What issue are you facing in following this answer: [retrieving and classifying Notes with time and date of creation](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113232)? As long as you've the DB file you can get the output into .txt or any other format.

Comment: 1) Is the default one, it just says _version 1.0_ **but** I'm downloading the app in the linked answer that you provided _and I'll update the question with the results (if there are like in the image sample)_. 2) I downloaded the ADB but, when I open the adb.exe, this only open and close inmediatelly _leaving me no change of check all commands shown on it._ and I don't have knowledge about how it works. I read the ADB info provided on android.se, but I don't understand well, after search videos, they download android SDK (but I _think_ that is not need for do it).

Comment: @Mauricio, you don't run the `adb` exe directly. Do a Shift+Right Click on the adb installation folder, select "Open command window here", and type `adb` in the command prompt that opens. You should then be able to use it, assuming the drivers are correctly set up.

Comment: A separate approach is mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS3/comments/2zd8og/location_of_data_for_memonote/cpjq9k3): use `adb shell run-as com.sec.android.app.memo cd /data/data/com.sec.android.app.memo ls -all` to know the name of text files and then pipe them into SD card for output. `Run-as` shouldn't be working but anyhow, the user reported success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieving and classifying Notes with time and date of creation](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113220/retrieving-and-classifying-notes-with-time-and-date-of-creation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, this is difficult, if not impossible, without ADB or root. However, I will try to make the adb part simple for you, so you can follow the rest of the answer.

1. Get this package: [Minimal ADB and fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790), and install it on your computer.
2. On your phone, go to Settings → Developer Options (On Android 4.2 and above, this option is normally hidden. Go to Settings → About Device, and tap on the build number entry 7 times. This will enable the Developer Settings option).
3. Under Developer options, select "Allow USB Debugging".
4. Connect your phone to the computer where you had installed ADB. If Windows starts installing drivers, let it finish.
5. Go to the ADB install folder, and Do a Shift+Right Click on the adb installation folder, select "Open command window here", and type `adb devices` in the command prompt that opens.
6. Your phone might pop up a request for authorization with an RSA Key, accept it.
7. If the prompt shows something like:

   `Connected devices:`

   `123456789ABCDEF device`

or variants thereof, you are good to follow the steps mentioned below:

<sub>The steps are taken from @Firelord 's answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113220/retrieving-and-classifying-notes-with-time-and-date-of-creation/113232#113232), almost verbatim. All credits to @Firelord</sub>

1. Take backup of your "Notes" app by issuing the following ADB command:

   ```
   adb backup <PACKAGE>
   ```

   where `<PACKAGE>` is the package name of the app whose backup you want to take. The file will be saved as `backup.ab` in the directory from where ADB is executed.

   In your case, you should end up with the backup file `backup.ab` (~1.7KiB) in your Home directory of GNU/Linux using the command:

   ```
   adb backup com.sec.android.app.memo
   ```

   <sub>This step is needed because I'm unaware (as a non-root user) of any other way to get your hands on an app's internal files residing in `/data`.</sub>
2. The `.ab` file may not be able to be opened on your PC so use [Android Backup Extractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/) (see usage in its `README.txt`) to convert into `.tar` archive which then can be opened by any archive viewer (like Ark, WinRAR, and so on).

   <sub>Some other methods to unpack the `.ab` file are mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/96277).</sub>
3. Open the converted file (`.tar` in case you used Android Backup Extractor) and locate `.db` file under **apps**→`<PACKAGE>`→**db**→`<.db>`.
4. Open that `.db` in an SQL viewer like [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). You can then export the file into `.csv` using **File → Export → Table(s) as CSV file**.
5. The resulting `.csv` can be viewed formatted in any spreadsheet software like MS Excel or even Google Sheets.

Comment: I tried running `adb backup com.sec.android.app.memo` but it creates an (almost) empty backup.ab file. I guess this requires a rooted phone. I also tried `adb shell run-as com.sec.android.app.memo cd /data/data/com.sec.android.app.memo ls -all` but I got the error: `run-as: Package 'com.sec.android.app.memo' is not debuggable`

Comment: @Fif It doesn't require root, but it will only work on the particular Samsung phones referred to, and I wouldn't expect it to work on more recent Android versions. If you still have problems, ask a new question.

Comment: @Fif this is a known problem with `adb backup`, see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116439/adb-backup-command-on-non-rooted-device-creates-an-empty-backup-file) - it might be an issue with backup protection passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this useful post.

to get adb on my linux : `urpmi android-tools`

On a Huawei Y330, Android 4.2.2, Package name of Notes app is: **com.example.android.notepad**
found it in app list from command line: ([here](https://gist.github.com/davidnunez/1404789))

`adb shell pm list packages | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'`

Then extracted backup with: ([here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/96277))

`java -jar abe.jar unpack <backup.ab> <backup.tar> <password>`