# Anyone know where memos are stored on a Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I hooked my S6 up to a Win8 computer, and there were about 30-something folders on the S6.  So I copied everything to my PC.  Now I'm trying to find some of the info that was on my phone, like memos, and I can't figure out which folder they're in.  They've got to be here somewhere.  Does anyone know which folder the memos are stored in?

By memos, I'm talking about the default memo app that comes with the Samsung S6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see: The package name of the *Memo* app on Samsung phones is called `com.samsung.android.app.memo`.
There is no such folder in `sdcard\Android\data`, so it has to be in `/data/data/`.

And how correct I am:
Using `adb shell` and giving myself root access (`su`) to access `/data`, I am able to explore my own private data.

[image]

Now let's look inside and we find a `databases` folder with a `memo.db` inside:

[image]

Using some simple SQL and `sqlite3` we can take a look inside the database itself:

[image]

There are our memos. Note that they are also saved as XML including any extra data needed for the app itself.

> Yes you need root access or use Samsung's backup tool to make a backup of your memos.

Comment: The poster [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/129079/96277) is certain that the app can be backed up using ADB  (i.e. no root access is required). However, it is always possible that the current Memo app in S6 doesn't allow backup. Can you confirm? Also, on which model and Android version have you tested your answer?

Comment: @Firelord using Smasung's SmartSwitch application it actually does a backup. `adb backup` only returns an empty backup file for `adb backup com.samsung.android.app.memo`.

Comment: "giving myself root access" - can you expand on this, please? Primarily, does this require that the device be rooted, and what is the command syntax to give myself root access to /data?