# Transferring SMemo Notes

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, s-memo

I am currently using `SMemo` on my Galaxy S3, I am about to get the Galaxy S7 Edge.  How would I transfer the notes from my `SMemo` app from my 3 to my 7?

(And I don't see a tag for the samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge so I could only tag the S3)

Comment: Is it the same app mentioned here: [Get notes created using "Notes" default app and export them to PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128678)?

Comment: @Firelord - that post seems to be about Notes, on my device the Galaxy S3 Notes and SMemo are two separate apps

Comment: Related, a bit: [Anyone know where memos are stored on a Samsung Galaxy S6?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131633)