# Android raw Memo files from PC back to android

Tags: file-transfer, data-transfer, s-memo

I used file transfer to copy the contents of my Galaxy S5 to my PC, thinking I had effectively "backed up" the data, then traded in the phone.

I had important notes about my daughter's first year (milestones, etc) saved in the Memo app. And of course, I'm now realizing I hadn't backed it up properly.

There seems to be a way to be able to get the files, as indicated in this post:
[Anyone know where memos are stored on a Samsung Galaxy S6?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131632/anyone-know-where-memos-are-stored-on-a-samsung-galaxy-s6)

I can work with XML files, and have tried to pay someone to extract this data, but nobody seems to understand what I've done or what I need. These memos are so important to me ... can anyone with expertise recommend a professional that I can pay to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the memo files on the pc also? If you're just trying to get them back to your phone it seems the easiest way would be to email them to yourself. The files should be in (.smm). Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't delete anything on the PC, but I also can't find any files with that extension. Only a file with a ".bk" extension ... which I think is a database?