# Where to find Memos app folder in Samsung Galaxy J3

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, battery, samsung-galaxy-j3, samsung-smart-switch

I am having a major problem with my Galaxy J3 (besides just being a J3 ^_^). The thing has been doing random reboots when in the middle of work, went to the bios screen a couple times, then started trying to install (an update?) which failed, then showed the android icon falling, syntax came up saying erasing, then started scrolling files and said "formatting".

In a panic, not knowing what that meant, I pulled out the battery and left it out a few minutes. When it was put back in it rebooted as normal but that was the last straw. Contacted Samsung and ordered a new phone. I've been successful with Smart Switch for the mains like contacts, photos etc. But Samsung neglected to clue me in that Smart Switch has to work for literally 2 days to move everything? Is this true?

Anyway, still need apps and "Memos" which had no visible backup and restore. All I can find is to manually share to Gmail which would take a LONG time since I have literally over 500 memos. Probably should have done it anyway because now the phone has gone to not powering on at all. I've had the battery tested and found it has some damage (over heating?) but the new battery isn't giving a charge.

At this point I could care less about the J3 phone (horrible thing) but I do need those memos for sure! Anyone know how to access them when the phone is apparently dead? Or where on the phone folders if connected to your laptop? Any recommended data recovery tools you can vouch for?

Don't mind paying a little for good results but of course free is always best if it does the job. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyone know where memos are stored on a Samsung Galaxy S6?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131632/anyone-know-where-memos-are-stored-on-a-samsung-galaxy-s6)