# Automated export of Samsung S-Note notes to image or PDF?

Tags: tasker, evernote, s-note

Are there any methods for automated export/transfer of Samsung [S-Note](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/04/19/how-to-master-s-note-on-the-samsung-galaxy-note-4/) notes to an image or PDF?

I understand how to *manually* export / share notes from within S-Note and am aware of S-Note to S-Note and S-Note to Evernote synchronization.  I'm hoping to find an alternative to Evernote synchronization which I currently rely on.

It would be perfect if this can be accomplished entirely within Android and accessible to Tasker.

This question was listed as a possible duplicate of ["Get notes created using “Notes” default app and export them to PC"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128678/get-notes-created-using-notes-default-app-and-export-them-to-pc).  These are not the same application.  [Here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/04/19/how-to-master-s-note-on-the-samsung-galaxy-note-4/) is a link showing S-Note.  Techniques used by that question may be applicable in this case, however; S-Note captures images which represent additional complexity when pulling data through that many layers.  The adb nature of that approach makes an automated solution even more difficult.

Comment: Is your Android rooted? I suppose the native notes app in question is the same app mentioned [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128678/96277). In that case, see if you can get some info from the app's content provider.  If you can't get anything, then I would say root access is the only way to at least get access to notes, let alone convert them to image or PDF.

Comment: adb won't be required if the Android is rooted. You've not given any clarification on rooting.

Comment: A rooted solution is reasonable although the phone is not presently rooted.