# Can't find webview.db file for android browser to view saved passwords in internet app

Tags: sqlite

I can't find this file anywhere.
Can anyone advise where this might be stored?
I downloaded SQLITE editor on my note 3 but it says no database.
When I see the internet icon under Apps in SQLite Editor in /data/data/com.sec.android.pp.sbrowser a pop up error says: "Root shell binary not found in standard location (or phone note rooted).

However, I rooted with Kingroot.

I need to recover all passwords stored in the android internet appl.

Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: You could try obtaining the app's data via ADB: `adb backup com.sec.android.pp.sbrowser`. Then extract the file from that backup (for details on ADB, see our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), and also our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), especially [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575)). Please report back if that works.

Answer (score 2):

[LG G2 4.4.2 rooted]

I couldn't find webview.db either but opening the file ACEBrowser.db which was in the data/data/com.android.browser/databases had all the required information under 'password'.

Took me hours to realise this. Hope this helps someone else to do so quicker :)