# How do I view Android application specific cache

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, cache, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I wan't to copy cache files of an application to see what it stores in cache. I've a non-rooted Galaxy Note 4 running android 5.1.1. Is there any way using adb or something else? This application is not built in debug mode. So I can't do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916829/how-do-i-view-android-application-specific-cache#comment38264317_24658933) But unlike what that question asks, I'm OK even if there are multiple steps to be done manually. That question asks about dynamically accessing it.

Comment: `adb backup PACKAGE`. If the app allows backup, you would get the backup as .AB file. Extract the backup using the solutions [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/how-do-you-extract-an-apps-data-from-a-full-backup-made-through-adb-backup) and find the cache inside the extracted content.